# how to write this grep regex

Tags: regex, shell, grep

```
if [ '`echo "$url" | grep (\.tar\.gz|\.tar\.bz2|\.zip|\.rar|\.7z)$`' ] ; then
```

syntax error, I just want to check file extension.

Comment: As shown, you shouldn't be getting an error, but it won't do what you intend.

Comment: @Dennis He will be getting an error, as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Marcog: no, he won't be getting a syntax error. `if [ '$(echo "$url" | grep (\.tar\.gz|\.tar\.bz2|\.zip|\.rar|\.7z)$)' ] ; then echo Hi; else echo Lo; fi` echoes Hi regardless of the value of `$url`.  (I changed backticks to `$(...)` to get the code echoed as code in the comment; you get the same result with backticks as in the original.)

Comment: @Jonathan You are correct. I was only executing the `grep`, so missed that part entirely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you need to remove the `''` as otherwise the test is just a string that always evaluates to true. You need to put the regex in quotes as parentheses are interpreted by bash. You also need to use `egrep` (equivalent to `grep -E`).

```
if [ `echo "$url" | egrep "(\.tar\.gz|\.tar\.bz2|\.zip|\.rar|\.7z)$"` ] ; then
```

You can also shorten the regex by factoring the `.` out of the group and grouping `tar.{gz,bz2}`:

```
if [ `echo "$url" | egrep "\.(tar\.(gz|bz2)|zip|rar|7z)$"` ] ; then
```

For future, please take note of the error bash gives you which tells you quite a lot: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token (` suggests that the error is around the `(`, which I've just shown you is exactly where the error lies.

[Jonathan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527395/how-to-write-this-grep-regex/4527466#4527466) offers more tips on improving the test.

Comment: first, it's grep -E (uppercase), and second, on most OS's, it's the default anyway (better safe than sorry, I guess)

Comment: @Malvolio Of course you're correct. Edited. It's not the default on Ubuntu at least.

Comment: first, it's "@Malvolio Of course you're correct *as always*" and second, nitpicking the work of others is my passion.

Comment: Malvolio isn't the only nitpicker around here - I can be the nitpicking curmudgeon too.  I've got a couple of gripes with the answer.  First (and most serious), the test is a no-op that always succeeds because of the single quotes around the expression.  No commands or variables are evaluated; the test always passes.  Second, assuming that detail is fixed, the quotes are mis-nested at the tail of the expression; the backtick should come after the double quote.

Comment: @Jonathan You're quite right, and your answer should be the accepted one. I'll fix the quotes, but I feel bad importing any more from your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Given:

> ```
> if [ '`echo "$url" | grep (\.tar\.gz|\.tar\.bz2|\.zip|\.rar|\.7z)$`' ] ; then
> ```

Of itself, this isn't a syntax error - any syntax error is probably nearby.

On the other hand, this doesn't do what you want, either.  The string between the square brackets is single-quoted; it is itself.  The test checks whether the string is empty (it isn't) and goes on to execute the code in the `then` clause.

You need to use something like:

```
if [ $(echo "$url" | grep -E '\.(tar\.gz|tar\.bz2|zip|rar|7z|tgz)$' ) ] ; then
```

- Use '`$(...)`' in preference to back-ticks.
- Use '`grep -E`' to activate extended regular expressions.
- Factor out the leading '.' of the extensions.
- Remember that '`.tgz`' is a valid (although rare) extension for gzipped tar files.

---

And then, as [Dennis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson) points out in a comment, you can observe that it is not necessary to use the test command or command substitution at all:

```
if echo "$url" | grep -E '\.(tar\.gz|tar\.bz2|zip|rar|7z|tgz)$' >/dev/null ; then
```

This checks the exit status of the pipeline, which is the exit status from `grep`, which will be 0 (success) if one of the suffixes was recognized and 1 (failure) if none of them was.  And then, if this is Bash that we're using, you can avoid the pipeline too:

```
if grep -E '\.(tar\.gz|tar\.bz2|zip|rar|7z|tgz)$' <<< "$url" >/dev/null ; then
```

And we can also avoid using a second process at all by rewriting the code to use a `case` statement:

```
case "$url" in
(*.tar.gz|*.tar.bz2|*.zip|*.rar|*.7z|*.tgz|*.xz)
    # Do what was in the 'then' clause
    ;;
(*) # Do what was in the 'else' clause
    ;;
esac
```

- Note that `.xz` is also a compression scheme that you might encounter.

Comment: +1 Perfect except that the square brackets and `$()` (command substitution) aren't necessary. `if echo ... | grep -qs ...` (GNU) or `if echo ... | grep ... >/dev/null 2>&1` (portable)

Comment: @Dennis: Fair comment - I didn't do that extra level of analysis. Must go and get that caffeine!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
grep -E '\.(tar\.gz|tar\.bz2|zip|rar|7z)$'
```

Comment: It is looking for '`.tar.gz`' and '`.tar.bz2`' extensions - you got a bit too enthusiastic about the rewrite.  And you have to enable ERE with `grep -E` (though there's a rumour elsewhere on the page that some edition of `grep` does '-E' by default - though I find that hard to believe since it flouts POSIX compliance).

Comment: interesting. wouldn't know myself about grep, but the quick googling i did i noticed quotes after for the regex to be contained in (and didn't see any -E). And I did get a little crazy with the grouping, oops.